# jquery background image fade

Tags: jquery, background-image, fadein

I am using jQuery to load ina background image that fills the page width / height. I have the following in the Head:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css({
    'background-image' : 'url({HTML_BASE}images/backgrounds/randoms/{BACK_IMG})',
        'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat',
        'background-position' : 'center top',
        'background-attachment': 'fixed',
        'background-size': '100% 100%',
    });
    $('#home-promo').innerfade({ 
        speed: 'slow', 
        timeout: 5000, 
        type: 'sequence', 
        containerheight: 'auto'
    });

    $('.model-search').innerfade({ 
        speed: 'slow', 
        timeout: 5000, 
        type: 'sequence', 
        containerheight: '393'
    });

});
```

This works fine and can be seen at http://projects.snowshtechnologies.com/golden_dragon/home/

I want the BG image to fade in from the black background colour. I have looked at a few other threads on Stack that suggest its not possible as a body element defined in css, but in this scenario the BG image is being loaded in by jQuery. How would I go about adding a fade in to this code to bring the image in with a nice fadein?

Comment: Not aware of any way to do this. You would nee to have your BG image in a separate element on which you were willing to set the opacity, something you can't do on the `body` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the body `background-color` to `black` and then make an element like a div, position it as `fixed` and then `fade` that in, the element which should fill the entire width and height of the browser's viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a container on top of the body at 100% width and height to fill the space available and if necessary specify a `z-index` to position it below other elements. Then set the background image of the container in CSS and set `opacity: 0`. Finally use jQuery's `fadeTo()` to transition to 100% opacity.

Answer (score -1):

With CSS3 transitions you could add a fade in to the background image. Therefore if you add the following property:

```
transition: background 0.5s;
```

To your body div, you could get a fade in for browsers that support it. However, this wouldn't be supported on browsers that do not support CSS3 transitions.